# Reputations on Stack Overflow deducted - Reason Unknown

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did I just lose some reputation without any explanation in my profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133299/why-did-i-just-lose-some-reputation-without-any-explanation-in-my-profile)

By Friday 8/06/2012 my reputations were **500+**. But today i.e on 11/06/2012 when I logged in to my Stack Overflow account, what is see is my reputation has come down to **384**. I haven't got any message from the Stack Overflow for the reason of this reduction,neither my account shows any record of downvoting that might have lead to the deduction of my reputation.

Can anyone help me through this as to whom and how should I contact?
Regards.

Comment: On your reputation page (http://stackoverflow.com/users/993348/sam-m?tab=reputation), have you ticked "show removed posts" at the bottom? It'll show you if the reputation was removed because a post got deleted (e.g. a question you asked, an answer you made, or a whole question you posted an answer on).

Comment: Go to your reputation tab - http://stackoverflow.com/users/993348/sam-m?tab=reputation - and click on the "show removed posts" option

Comment: I believe it is in relation to a post which you made on March 28th. "User was Removed" See this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130122/more-descriptive-user-was-removed-explanation

Comment: @ChrisF thanks so much.So if the post is remove my Reputation will be lost?But the Question that was removed , i answer that question and it was marked as answer.But the issue is my answer didnt had reputation worth 143 due to upvote or any other reason.So why is 143 reputations being removed from my Account?

Comment: @SamM - I'm not a moderator on Stack Overflow so I can't see this information in your profile. This means I can't tell what else may have gone on.

Comment: @SamM - There were two posts that were removed on that day. Did you check both?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - There was one post removed and i have couple of downvotes too worth -2 reputation.

Comment: @SamM: I can see two "User was Removed" on Mar 20th. One for `-195` and the other for `-85` totaling to `-280`

Comment: @SamM You got your half of your reputation from your best friend ?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - ya ur right but that was way back in March.even after those deduction i gained reputation which were again deducted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295549/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-beginsavetfa-on-calling-the-function-on-onc/10295687#10295687) was removed, which was indeed worth 143 reputation to you...the system is behaving correctly.  You *do* see this when clicking "show removed posts", though it's not linked since you don't yet have 10k+ reputation.

Not to be mean...but looking at your annotations, I don't believe you'll want to discuss the reason for the removal in public, so I'll leave it out of this answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i surely would want to know the reason for the removal of the post , if the removal of the post was due to my posted answer.Was the answer not up to the standard?

Comment: @SamM - the question was closed as Too Localised and deleted almost immediately afterwards.

Comment: Interesting, the bounty is also removed. But it is still visible in the awarding user's page. Is it lost or is it refunded?

Comment: @Gamecat Seems to have been refunded, there's no record of it in the user's reputation page.

Comment: @Gamecat the bounty was lost